# How to setup 2 domain at the same nginx server, 1st on HTTPS, 2nd on HTTP?

Tags: nginx, http, https

I have a nginx config like this
**First Block:**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name abcd.info;
    return 301  https://$host$request_uri;
        }

    server {
        listen  443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name abcd.info;
        root /srv/www/abcd; ## <== Your only path reference.
        #ssl    on;
    .....
    .....
    }
```

**Second Block**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name tapash.ddns.com;
root    /srv/www/ddns.com;
index   index.php;

......
....
}
```

For the first site, I want to setup over HTTPS permanently. Problem I am facing is to serve the 2nd site on HTTP. But everytime it automatically redirects to HTTPS and take the SSL certificate of first site. I tried to adjust configs but seems no difference. Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: If your configs are in separate files, are you absolutely sure that the second block is being read and loaded? There may be a typo in your filename or similar meaning it doesn't match the wildcard for loading configurations.

Comment: They are actually in the same file. But I will try on a different file now.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I have placed them in 2 different files now and still the same. I have double checked for typos, but everything is perfectly in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

site1.example.net

```
server {
    listen 192.168.1.1;
    server_name site1.example.net;

    root /vhosts/site1/public_html;

    location / {
        add_header X-DEBUG "HTTP:[site1.example.net]" always;
    }

}
```

site2.example.net

```
server {
    listen 192.168.1.1:80;
    server_name site2.example.net;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    add_header X-DEBUG "HTTP:[site2.example.net]" always;
}

server {
    listen  443 ssl hhtp2;
    server_name site2.example.net;

    root /vhosts/site2/public_html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/nginx/server.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:!RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    add_header X-DEBUG "HTTPS:[site2.example.net]" always;
}
```

Works as it should, no redirects for site1 on http

```
# curl -I http://site1.example.net
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.11
Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2016 09:08:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 45
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Feb 2016 08:54:51 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "56cc1e5b-2d"
X-DEBUG: HTTP:[site1.example.net]
Accept-Ranges: bytes


# curl -I http://site2.example.net
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.9.11
Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2016 09:08:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://site2.example.net/
X-DEBUG: HTTP:[site2.example.net]


# curl -I https://site2.example.net/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.11
Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2016 09:08:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 45
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Feb 2016 08:55:02 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "56cc1e66-2d"
X-DEBUG: HTTPS:[site2.example.net]
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

P.S.
maybe some cache in your web browser. Have you tried to clear it?

Answer (score -1):

you may be using server block inside another server block, or I just saw bad formated blocks.
But the real problem is default_server tag you are using. Remove it.

I would recommend using two separate files inside /sites-available/ folder named abcd.info and tapash.ddns.com.

You need put your files in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ folder 
then create symbolic links to to those files in sites-enabled like this:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/abcd.info /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abcd.info
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/tapash.ddns.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/tapash.ddns.com
```

and lastly but very important remove the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

since with the regular nginx installation this is the default file that will be processed. And any file that you have in /sites-enabled will be processed.

if you are working this on localhost make sure your hosts file has records for tapash.ddns.com and abcd.info

Comment: removing default_server directive didnt really help. nor placing the config into 2 separate files.

Comment: Yeah, the default_server option only manually specifies a server block to take precedence if there were no more specific matches found in the blocks listening on that port. Splitting up your config into partials in separate files and using includes to bring them together is recommended because it makes maintaining a configuration easier but as long as the syntax in all of them is good and they're being included properly it has no effect on function.

Comment: removing default_server is a must for any other work. BTW, where have you placed your 2 separated files?